# Rotating left is rotating right

Tags: c++, assembly, rotation

In C++ I want to rotate an array of 4 characters once to the left using the assembly instruction ROL. I thought I'd interpret the array as a dword and rotate this dword once to the left and this would do what I wanted. Instead, whenever I rotate the dword once to the left it's rotating once to the right. This is my ASM code:

```
ShiftRow proc
; copy array into EAX
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR [RCX]
ROL EAX, 8
MOV DWORD PTR [RDX], EAX
RET
ShiftRow endp
```

and this is how my C++ code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void __fastcall RotateArray(const char* Array, char* OutputArray);

int main()
{
    char input_array[] = {0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40};

    char output_array[4] = {};
    RotateArray(input_array, output_array);


    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)output_array[i] << " ";
    cin.get();
}
```

Strangely enough (to me) output is 40 10 20 30 even though I was shifting to the left. Can someone explain me why this is happening? Does this have something to do with endianness?

Comment: Yes, this is due to endianness. Look at the memory in the debugger, specifically for how a _real_ dword is stored, to understand more.

Comment: @Dave Newman - Your comment is incorrect. On little ended machines the lowest address is in the least significant byte (i.e. right most byte), so he starts with `0x40302010`. When this is rotated left he has `0x30201040`. Reading out from the lowest address at the right gives the result he observes.

Comment: Yup. You can fix this with a bswap instruction before the rol.

Comment: @mah - a ***real*** dword eh? What sort of dwords do big-endian machines use? Plastic? :-p

Comment: @enhzflep I am making a distinction between an actual dword and a string of characters you tell the CPU to treat as a dword... the latter is not stored in the order you need it to be when you're on a little endian machine.

Comment: @mah - Thank-you for taking the time to add the clarification. It seems so obvious now that I read it. Cheers. :-)

Comment: @user2151446 - You're correct. I mangled that. 0x40302010 is the right starting value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is due to endianness, and your machine is a little-endian machine.
This is what is happening:

input_array before rotation: `10, 20, 30, 40`

EAX before rotation        : `40 30 20 10`

EAX after rotation         : `30 20 10 40`

output_array after rotation : `40, 10, 20, 30`

Comment: "your machine is probably a little-endian machine" : There are not many machines that can execute x86 assembly that are not little-ended!